# the screenshot is not getting displayed in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, cookies, phantomjs

I'am trying to get the high quality screenshot of the webpage.But it is not displaying the screenshot.Only the portion of the webpage is getting displayed.when i try to get the screenshot which doesn't need any cookie it is giving the screenshot properly but when i try using cookie it displays nothing(only a very very small portion is getting displayed).
This is how i have written my code.

```
'use strict';
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address, output, pixelRatio, width, height;
page.cookiesEnabled = true;

//i have added some of the cookies here which my page requires to load

var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(system.args, 1);

address = 'myurl';
output = 'd:/screenshots/11.png';
pixelRatio = 2;

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};

// Here we block the first (few) requests until we have set the correct window variables
var resources = [];
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, networkRequest) {
    if((requestData.url.match(/\.js/g) !== null || requestData.url.match(/\/js\//g) !== null)) {
        if(requestData.url.match(/_phantomLoadMe/g) === null && requestData.url.match(/typekit/gi) === null) {
            console.log('Temporarily blocking too soon request to ', requestData['url']);
            resources.push(requestData['url']);
            networkRequest.abort();
        }
    }

    var reqUrl = requestData.url;
    var newUrl = requestData.url.split(',%20')[0];

    if (newUrl != reqUrl) {
      networkRequest.changeUrl(newUrl);
    }
};

width = (1440*pixelRatio);
height = (900*pixelRatio);

page.viewportSize = { width: width, height: height };
page.settings.localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled = true;
page.settings.userAgent = 'Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0';

page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!', address, status);
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        // Manipulate the DOM
        page.evaluate(function (r, urls, width, height) {
            console.log('Setting window.devicePixelRatio to ' + r);
            window.devicePixelRatio = r;
            window.onload = false;
            window.innerWidth = (width/r);
            window.innerHeight = (height/r);
            document.documentElement.offsetWidth = (document.documentElement.offsetWidth/r);
            document.documentElement.offsetHeight = (document.documentElement.offsetHeight/r);
            document.documentElement.clientWidth = (document.documentElement.clientWidth/r);
            document.documentElement.clientHeight = (document.documentElement.clientHeight/r);
            screen.width = width;
            screen.height = height;
            document.body.style.webkitTransform = "scale(" + r + ")";
            document.body.style.webkitTransformOrigin = "0% 0%";
            document.body.style.width = (100 / r) + "%";

            // Now that we've set our window, let's get those scripts again
            var _phantomReexecute = [];
            var _phantomScripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
            _phantomScripts = Array.prototype.slice.call(_phantomScripts);
            if(_phantomScripts.length > 0) {
                _phantomScripts.forEach(function(v) {
                    if('src' in v && v.src !== "" && v.src.match(/typekit/gi) === null) {
                        urls.push(v.src);
                    }
                    else {
                        _phantomReexecute.push({'script': v.innerHTML});
                    }
                });
            }
            var _phantomAll = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
            for (var _phantomIndex = _phantomAll.length - 1; _phantomIndex >= 0; _phantomIndex--) {
                if(_phantomAll[_phantomIndex].src.match(/typekit/gi) === null) {
                    _phantomAll[_phantomIndex].parentNode.removeChild(_phantomAll[_phantomIndex]);
                }
            }
            var _phantomHead = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            if(urls.length > 0) {
                urls.forEach(function(u) {
                    var _phantomScript = document.createElement("script");
                    _phantomScript.type = "text/javascript";
                    _phantomScript.src = u + '?_phantomLoadMe';
                    _phantomHead.appendChild(_phantomScript);
                });
            }
            if(_phantomReexecute.length > 0) {
                _phantomReexecute.forEach(function(s) {
                    var _phantomScript = document.createElement("script");
                    _phantomScript.type = "text/javascript";
                    _phantomScript.innerHTML = s.script;
                    _phantomHead.appendChild(_phantomScript); 
                });
            }

            // Make sure to execute onload scripts
            var _phantomCount = 0;
            var _phantomIntVal = setInterval(function() {
                if(window.onload !== false && window.onload !== null) {
                    window.onload();
                    clearInterval(_phantomIntVal);
                }
                _phantomCount++;

                if(_phantomCount > 10) {
                    clearInterval(_phantomIntVal);
                }
            }, 100);
        }, pixelRatio, resources, width, height);

        // Make the screenshot
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render(output);
            page.release();
            phantom.exit();
        }, 500000);
    }
```